# Unable to connect internet on raspberry pi using buildroot?

Tags: kernel, raspberry-pi, buildroot, network-connection

I have compiled the "buildroot-2014.05" for the raspberry pi device by using raspberrypi_defconfig which is provided by them and successfully booted with the new fresh kernel but, unable to connect to the internet connection from the newly booted kernel and also not having access to the basic tools like shell and similar kind of tools.
So, my question is this will it be possible to compile the kernel with our specified configuration so that I can choose the packages in which I am interested. In my case, internet connection is most important thing for the fresh kernel build.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Please answer it. It is important for project work.

Comment: What do you see on your console, when you boot?

Comment: After the boot, login prompt comes up, but I am unable to connect with the ethernet also unable to have access for the basic functional commands, I had followed the steps provided in the file board/raspberrypi/readme.txt from buildroot-2014.05. My question is this, will it be possible for me to modify the config file, which is in buildroot-2014.05/configs/raspberrypi_defconfig, so that I can add my own dependencies which I am intrested and if it’s possible then tell me the solution for the same, through which I can add the contents for modifying this file?

Comment: I've looked at the default config and it has really not that many packages selected. Execute `make raspberrypi_defconfig`. After this you can execute `make busybox-menuconfig` to select BusyBox utilities and `make menuconfig` will let you select other packages. Just read the [manual](http://nightly.buildroot.org/manual.html). It has answers on almost all your questions.

Comment: Thanks I read the manual and also compiled the kernel using make menuconfig, but I am new for the kernel compilation and all so, not that much friendly with the packages selection and all so unable to find out which packages will be for what, So if you have any links or something good material to study through which I can understand the process please revert me for that.

Answer (score 2):

Some useful links:

1. [BR RPi Tutorial](http://cellux.github.io/articles/diy-linux-with-buildroot-part-1/)
2. [BusyBox](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-busybox/)
3. [network setup](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/setting-up-an-network-interfaces-file/)
4. [iproute2 tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-iproute2-tools-to-manage-network-configuration-on-a-linux-vps)

Please check, if you have a network interface (eth0 or usb0), i.e. execute following command and provide its output:

```
ip addr
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this step by step [tutorial](http://userk.co.uk/minimal-raspberry-pi-article/) to install a minimal linux distribution for Raspberry Pi using Buildroot.

Main steps are:

- Format the sd-card with Gparted or fdisk.
- Download Buildroot
- Load the default configuration: raspberrypi_defconfig (this is just a basic configuration)
- Add the packages you want thanks to BusyBox (<- Select what you need)
- Post-Build configuration (SSH, ETH0 static or dynamic IP address)

The final product occupies 15Mb of Ram.

Hope it helps